# How to show home and back navigation icons in ToolbarAndroid in React Native

Tags: android, react-native

I want to add home and back icons to the toolbar but they don't seem to appear on the app. Am I missing somthing

```
    <ToolbarAndroid
    title='TestApp'
    navIcon={require('image!ic_menu_black_24dp')}
    style={styles.toobar}/>
```

Comment: Haven't used this yet, but check out https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Examples/UIExplorer/ToolbarAndroidExample.android.js . There are a ton of examples there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one by adding to the main layout in activity:

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

Comment: I am tying to keep 100% react-native app and therefore don't have any layouts created manually. I am trying to follow the documentation [link] (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/toolbarandroid.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [Icon.ToolbarAndroid](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#usage-with-toolbarandroid) with [router-flux](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux)

```
<Icon.ToolbarAndroid
iconColor='white'
navIconName={'md-arrow-back'}
onIconClicked={this.actionBack}/>
```

And pop method toT back

```
actionBack = () => {
    Actions.pop();
}
```